# Geolocation - Displaying distance of accounts on Map

Tags: javascript, geolocation, salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have build a Geolocation app that displays the location of an Account on a map. However to improe and take it further, I have decided to add a function that displays the "Distance" of the account to the person that is viewing the map.

After days of research, this is how far I have come but I still cant get it work. So please if anyone knows what i am doing wrong or how to make it work, please let me know!

My Code:

```
public with sharing class AccountController {
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Account> findAll() {
return [SELECT id, name, Location__Latitude__s, Location__Longitude__s, Industry
        FROM Account
        WHERE Location__Latitude__s != NULL AND Location__Longitude__s != NULL
        LIMIT 50];
DISTANCE(GEOLOCATION(BillingLatitude , BillingLongitude ),
Account_Name__r.GeoLocation__Latitude__s , Branch_Assigned__r.GeoLocation__Longitude__s )  , 
'mi')         
}}
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you are going to need to know:

1. The id of the account. (The `AccountId` variable below)
2. The latitude and longitude coordinates of the user's current location. (The `Latitude` and `Longitude` variables below)
   I should probably add here that you are going to need a way to collect the latitude and longitude coordinates of where the user is currently located, which in the web browser could be with the javascript [geolocation api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation).

That information can be fed into the following query:

```
Id AccountId = '0010I00001qh9r0';
Decimal Latitude  = 37.775;
Decimal Longitude = -122.418;

list<Account> Accounts = [ 
    SELECT Id
         , DISTANCE ( 
             Location__c 
           , GEOLOCATION( :Latitude , :Longitude ) 
           , 'km' 
           ) Distance
    FROM Account
    WHERE Id = :AccountId
];

for ( Account a : Accounts ) System.debug( a );
```

Which will give you the distance:

> Account:{Id=0010I00001qh9r0QAA, Distance=1.6328418223544767}